# Need and example using panache Reactive JPA

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I found the quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache extension but I couldn't find an example of it  using Panache orm with reactive repositories (In my case I use postgresql).

PanacheRepositoryBase.java seems that works as I need (smallrye.mutiny.*), could anybody link me to an example?

Thanks in advace, and nice work on quarkus project.

Regards

Comment: Waiting for the same here too. Tried to migrate an existing complex mapping to Reactive Hibernate but gets weird exceptions like "Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate collection persister org.hibernate.reactive.persister.collection.impl.ReactiveOneToManyPersister". Searched it but Google god failed me!!

Comment: Hi @KrishnaKumar, as a workarround we migrated to panacheRepositories and encapuslate all operations on Multi/Uni (smallrye) to maintain the reactive signature and behaviour. Is not the good approach, but for now ... 
public class MyEntityRepositoryImpl implements PanacheRepository<MyEntity>,MyEntityRepository  {

 public Uni<MyEntity> findMyEntityById(Long id) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(findById(id)).onItem().transform(mapper::toEntity);
 }
But, you found the "could not instatiate..."error  when building native image on quarkus?

Comment: Hi Dani, I got everything working here. My error was due to using "@ElementCollection" which the reactive hibernate doesn't support yet as per "https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive" Limitations section.                                                But when I created the native image, the old exception is back again!!  Yes, I am also returning Uni/Multi..... Trying to solve that now. No documentation or support is a major headache!!! . I am not using the Repository pattern but extending PanacheEntityBase for the entities.

Comment: So yes, everything's working in quarkusDev but not in native image!!

Comment: Hi, thats because ReactivePneToManyPersister works using reflection and native imagen not enables reflection defaults. To be able to use ReactiveOneToManyPersiser (or any other reflection util classes) you have to register this classes as reflection-enabled on native build.

Comment: To enable thirdparty jar classes to be marked to be used with reflection on native execution follow this steps: I prepared a github to example with the configuration https://github.com/danipenaperez/quarkus-enable-native-reflection  . Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Dani, I am trying to solve the native image problem with the insight you provided.  As I told that I extend PanacheEntityBase and use the find() and other findBy methods to fetch entities, but for persisting, the persist() method doesn't work as is. So I am injecting Mutiny.SessionFactory factory; and using its factory.withTransaction((session, transaction) -> {} ) methods for persisting. Curious to know how you deal with it.

Comment: Hi Krishna, using PanacheRepository we dont longer use hibernate-reactive (MutinysessionFactory). You can use directly EntityManger at PanacheRepositories this.getEntityManager() and deal with jpa in a standar way. And to mainatin signature use   Uni.createFrom().item(this.getEntityManager().merge(obj)); . hope helps.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try the Repository pattern then.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** A quickstart is now available on the Quarkus quickstarts development branch: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/development/hibernate-reactive-panache-quickstart

**Old answer:**

I've just created a new quickstart for Hibernate Reactive with Panache in Quarkus:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/pull/809

Hopefully, it will be included soon in the list of quickstarts, but you can have a look already if you want to play with it.

Comment: yeah Davide, great news!!.  I will try it.

Comment: This sadly doesn't solve my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72064316/quarkus-reactive-getting-started-put-and-delete-operations . Can you answer it?

I'm about to give up on Quarkus and just go with Spring Boot. The guide says something different, this repo says something different. Is the Quarkus API that unstable?

Comment: I will have a look